# Keras ImageDataGenerator + imgaug

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am a newbie on ML and I have recently discovered `imgaug` library exists https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .

I know about `ImageDataGenerator` class from keras, but I am missing something on this data augmentation, and is *coloring* an image. (What on photoshop blend mode is color).

I've seen `imgaug` has this kind of augmentation, but I was wondering if I can include it on my keras `ImageDataGenerator` class, so I can still pass the generator to the `fit` method.

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: `ImageDataGenerator` takes a `preprocessing_function` argument where you can specify the function you want to use for additional augmentations.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that exists. But for example, if my own augmentation is coloring the picture, when ever I pass my function to the ``preprocessing_function``, the augmentations ``ImageDataGenerator`` class has will be gone?

Comment: No it will run `preprocessing_function` after doing the other augmentations